# exporting variable from ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I print files from an array (that is stored in my app.js file) to a website using a for-loop in ejs:

```
<% for(let i = 0;i<posts.length; i++){ %>
    <li class="listtitle">
         <%= posts[i].title %>
      </li>
  <% } %>
```

Now I want to be able to remove a specific object from my array, I would use

```
array.splice(i,1)
```

The problem is that I don’t know how to export the “i” variable of a specific looped item from my ejs file to my app.js

(using node and express)

Comment: So you want to edit the content of the `posts` array?

Answer (score 0):

Constant data like this stored in memory. store in front-end memory instead.

Otherwise, you need to implement an api route, and send a http request and refresh or change dom in browser to deal with this question.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that on the trigger of an event you want to delete one of the posts. You can do that using the post method provided by jQuery.
The JavaScript file would be as follows:

```
let posts = document.querySelectorAll(".listtitle");
for(let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
    posts[i].addEventListener('event_name', function(){
        $.post('/route_name', {index: i}, function(data){
            //perform whatever changes you want to do in the front end
        });
    });
```

The above code sends a POST request to '/route_name' on the trigger of 'event_name', and after the completion of the request you can return some data which is passed as argument to the callback function. The app.js file should have the following middleware:

```
app.post('route_name', function(req, res){
    //req.body would contain the data sent through the request, in this case req.body.index
    //access and make changes to the database
    //After making changes you can return some data which will be passed to the callback 
    res.send(posts);
});
```

> Make sure to include the body-parser module, otherwise you would not be able to access the data in a req.body object and you will probably get an error.

You can also use the http request object to perform the ajax request but i usually prefer to use jQuery.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I found a way that works better for me since I don't really use jquery by just using a hidden input field

Answer (score 0):

Okay so in case anyone else has the same problem, I used a hidden input field in a form that looks like this:

```
  <input id="prodId" name="prodId" type="hidden" value=<%= i %>>
```

i is the variable and you can access it in the app.js via req.body.prodId